# Ratio of triangle areas

Tags: geometry

[image]

In the above diagram, I have to compute the ratio of the areas of the triangles $\Delta AOB\ \& \ \Delta AOD.$

It is easy to see that $\Delta AOB\sim \Delta COD\implies \frac{\text{ar }(\Delta AOB)}{\text{ar }(\Delta(COD)}=\left(\frac{OB}{OD}\right)^2=\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^2.$ But how to find out the required ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\Delta AOB$ and $\Delta AOD$ share the same height.
Therefore, $$\frac{[\Delta AOB]}{[\Delta AOD]} = \frac{OB}{OD}.$$

If you are not sure why they share the same height, try to draw the heights out explicitly. In that case, let $h$ be the common height, then
$$\frac{[\Delta AOB]}{[\Delta AOD]} = \frac{0.5\times h \times OB}{0.5\times h \times OD}=\frac{OB}{OD}.$$